# CSS Image background is not taking effect on margin

Tags: css

Why does my background image doesn't repeat in the margin area?
There's how to make margin background transparent or something like that?
So it will aloow the background page to appears.

Here's the image of the issue (the red line it's just a div border that I've added to debug):
[image]

Here's my CSS code:

```
html { 
  background: url(/img/bg.png); 
  background-repeat:repeat;
}

table.display {
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

#dt_div  {
    border: red 4px dashed;
    width:96%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

---

And HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.datatables.net/favicon.ico" />

        <title>DataTables Editor example</title>
        <style class="include" type="text/css">
            @import "support/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css";
            @import "support/bootstrap/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css";
            @import "css/customTable.css";
        </style>

        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../../media/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../../media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../TableTools/media/js/TableTools.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../../TableTools/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../media/js/dataTables.editor.js"></script>

        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="support/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="support/bootstrap/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="support/bootstrap/dataTables/dataTables.editor.bootstrap.js"></script>

        <script class="include" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./js/custom.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            aDataInitial = '<?php  echo json_encode($stack);?>';
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="c_body" style="border: red 4px dashed;">
        <div id="mContainer" style="border: red 4px dashed;">
            <div id="dt_div">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered display" id="example">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Data</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Tema</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">V&iacute;nculo</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Empresa</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Sub contratada</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">NDP</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">CH</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">HHT</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Ger&ecirc;ncia</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">&Aacute;rea Solicitante</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">CC</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Rateio</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Fabio Cardoso, I thought I had no permission to post images :)

Comment: Can you post a link to your site as this problem does not make sense as a div will have no bg by default and the body bg would show through. If i had a link to your site i'd be able to tell you the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `background-image`.

```
html { 
  background: url(/img/bg.png); 
  background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

should be

```
body { 
  background-image: url('/img/bg.png'); 
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

You can also lump all options into `background` as shown in the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background (When using `background` you can still specify `background-image`, `background-repeat`, etc. after to override.)

Comment: In general, avoid trying to style the `html` tag.  However, it is often useful to add class values to the `html` tag that can be used to invoke specific CSS cascades.

Comment: This is false. You do not need `background-image` to specify the URL. `background` is a shorthand property. As such you can use URLs for an image in there as well. The problem probably simply lies in the use of the shorthand property for the URL but still using `background-repeat` separately. Try `background: url('/img/bg.png') repeat;` instead.

Comment: @BramVanroy That's pretty much what I said. I said it could be done with just `background` but that the OP clearly intended to specify the `background-image`.

Comment: *You should use background-image to specify the url.* is ambiguous at least. You do not need to use the `background-image` property. A better formulation could be: *you cannot use the `background-repeat` property separately from the shorthand `background` property.Instead, put everything together in `background` or use `background-image` instead of `background`*.